# Как убрать shell при использовании tkinter? (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создаю программу с tkinter. У меня при выводе получается shell и само приложение.

Как убрать shell, чтобы осталась только программу?

Comment: Какая операционная система, как запускаете? Если под windows просто двойным щелчком по файлу, то поменяйте расширение с py на pyw.

Comment: windows. заработало. Спасибо